# How do i include fusionchart in tcpdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf, fusioncharts

Im using fusionchart in my projecs and i would like to use fusionchart in tcpdf...the chart is loading correctly in my php page but not in pdf generated by tcpdf

### Edit

Okay i guess i need to save the chart as a graphic and then include that graphic in  TCPDF i tried it something like this in my php page nothing is save

```
$webpageURLWithChart = "chart1.php";
$outputImageFileName = "images/charts/savedImage.jpg";
$delay = 500;
$shellout = shell_exec("C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe --javascript-delay $delay $webpageURLWithChart $outputImageFileName" );

echo $shellout;
```

http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/

Comment: You'll need to save the chart as a graphic and then include that graphic in your PDF.

Comment: thank you ...i edited my question ..still trying to figure this out